# form does not hide after click

Tags: vb.net, winforms

solved my last question. but now I am on a little wall today..

help me get some workarounds in this code. its suppose to `hide` the `visible` form instance when I click the marker again, but instead, its creating a new form instance, as from what I can see, they should be doing both things that I mentioned. lol

```
For Each m In mList
            If item.ToolTipText = m Then
                Dim f As New Form2
                With f
                    If .Visible = True Then
                        .Hide()
                    Else
                        .Show()
                        Dim p As New Point
                        p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
                        .Location = p
                        .Text = m
                    End If
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
```

my **Goal** is to `hide` the opened instance after I clicked it again. Thanks for helping out!

**UPDATE** I have added `Dim f As New Form2` every click because I have many markers that must be shown at the same time depending on how many forms the user wants to see. If I use that declaration at global, it will only produce one at a time. so I need to create a new instance per click, and if I click again, the `visible` instance will `hide`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating a new form in your code every time:

```
Dim f As New Form2
```

You need to reference an existing instance of a form but from your code it's not clear where you store it.

Comment: I have tried that one, and added it to the top. but if I do that, I can only `show` one form at a time.. that's not an option for me :) I'll update my question.

Comment: Do you want to hide a form when you click anywhere inside it?

Comment: well, let's see the code if it meets the need. better yet hide the form after clicking X ... so it won't give me the `dispose` error. :)

Comment: If you need to hide a form when you click on it, you should handle the 'Click' event of the form (within the form code).

Comment: well, if I do that, yes that `form` will hide.. but if I click the marker, it will create another, hide, create, hide, create.. that's a lot of load for the app :(

Comment: wouldn't it have a negative effect? :/ I can't use that, its not advisable for an app with 24/7 usage. at the right time, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

did another workaround..

added `Me.Hide()` on `form2` closing event.. I really don't know if it hides or something..

but when I click the marker again, it does not give me a `dispose` error

```
For Each m In mList
            If item.ToolTipText = m Then
                Dim f As New Form2
                With f
                    .Show()
                    Dim p As New Point
                    p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)
                    .Location = p
                    .Text = m
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
```